# Storing previous (this) to hide the previously clicked event

Tags: jquery, variables, button

I'm doing a map with a bunch of buttons you can click on, you can check the wip here:

http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/index.html

I have a button issue. You click on a button on the map with id's: #world_map1, #world_map2 etc... and a panel appears. I'm using Jquery name filtering to do this. Inside the function I use .this to refer to the selector of the panel that needs to be shown using the name of the button ie. #world_map_1_panel_container.

This all works. I made it so that when you click the map, everything dissapears.

But I'm trying to hide the panel on display when a new button is clicked. I tried using variables but I'm a bit stuck because of the local scope I think. And I am looking for a more effective method.

---

Here you click the button and the panel is shown.

```
$('#'+'[id^="world_map"]').click(function() {

     var that = this.id;

        $('#' +that+ '_panel_container')
                .css('visibility','visible')
                .css('display','inline')
                .css('z-index','8000')
                .animate({"opacity" : 1}, 150, function() { });
```

These hide the active panels when a button is clicked, I move them to the back.

```
        $('#world_map_1').click(function() {    $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_2').click(function() {    $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_3a').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_3b').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_4').click(function() {    $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_5a').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_5b').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_6').click(function() {    $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_71').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_72').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_73').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_8').click(function() {    $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_9').click(function() {    $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_10').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_11').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });
        $('#world_map_12').click(function() {   $('#' +that+ '_panel_container').css('z-index','-8000');        });

});
```

This works but is very unstable. On the world map everything works smoothly. But as you  click on the magnifying glass of the middle east, the same principle is applied but for a different map but for some reason the browser doesn't send the layers to -8000.

If you need more info on html or css please ask, I've been looking at this code for an entire day without luck...

this is the complete script I use for the world_map, the middle_east_map and cuba_map.
http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/js/script.js

this is the script I use for the mouseovers, zoom and other things.
http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/js/finalcode.js

css for the maps can be found here (draggable stuff)
http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/css/fixed_elements.css

css for the panels can be found here:

http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/css/world_map_panels.css
http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/css/middle_east_map_panels.css

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution for you. You don't need so many `click` event handlers for all the world maps to restore the `zIndex` values.

```
var zIndex = 8000;
$('#'+'[id^="world_map"]').click(function() {

     var that = this.id;

        $('#' +that+ '_panel_container')
                .css('visibility','visible')
                .css('display','inline')
                .css('z-index', zIndex++)
                .animate({"opacity" : 1}, 150, function() { });
});
```